# Amplify and impedance match a low voltage signal

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, impedance, pulse

Situation: I am trying to trigger an external generator using the 1 Pulse Per Second (PPS) off a GPS receiver. The GPS receiver outputs a ~3.3Vp at high impedance once per second once the GPS receiver has reliable position. In order for my external generator to recognize the pulse, the input must be greater than ~3.6Vp and have a low impedance (~50 ohms).

Since the reference 1PPS signal is triggering an external generator, this circuit must have a very small time delay.

Does anyone know of a "simple" circuit to achieve such a job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

High input impedance using the excellent 2N7000 FET ( GATE DRIVE ONLY 3V ) then feeding a PNP transistor with 50ohm o/p.

Optionally, change the 10K to 47K or even 100K.

[image]

Comment: Note that the [2N7000](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N7000.pdf) is one of those *truly-ESD-sensitive* devices. The gate is very easily destroyed by static electricity.

Comment: Been using it for many years and never had a failure. But still good advice.

Comment: The three resistors between the FET and PNP transistor are just silly.  Two would do everything that needs to be done.

Comment: Show me, i love to learn! @ Olin

Answer (score 0):

You have various options but one easy one is an opto-coupler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCiG06.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Set R1 to set the opto-LED current to 10 mA at 1.2 V across LED. R1 = (3.3 - 1.2) / 10m = 220 Ω.
- Use Q1 to pull the next stage input high or low as required. Pull-up / pull-down resistor should not be required.

[Edit:]

The [Toshiba TLP523](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/08e0/0900766b808e044e.pdf) may suffice for this task. It has a Darlington output stage. The data sheet shows a 1.2 V drop across the output transistor with 100 mA through the output at 10 mA LED current. OP doesn't state the voltage available to the step-up function, but if it's 5 V then this device should deliver 3.8 V to the 50 Ω input.

[image]

> Since the reference 1PPS signal is triggering an external generator,
>   this circuit must have a very small time delay.

Turn on and off times are quoted at 3 and 80 μs (Vcc = 10 V, RL = 180 Ω, If = 16 mA).

Comment: Have you looked at specific parts to guarantee 72 mA into 50 ohms? I thought not.

Comment: Ouch! See the update. It's actually the first time I've looked at 50 Ω circuits. OP was vague about supply voltage available at the load end so I'm still not sure this will work. There is no mention of distance between the GPS and the external generator (whatever that is) so I have not considered impedance matching but rather just yank the input high with the Darlington. Is this a mistake?

Comment: That one looks OK. And if you can't guarantee a 5 volt circuit, you can put the optocoupler in the base circuit of a transistor.